# How to pass parameters between Lambda Functions in AWS Step Functions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have tried to look throught the internet, but none of the solutions seem to work for me in python. Basicly I want to transfer some parameters from one lambda function to the next lambda function in a step function. I was a bit surprised how hard it is to find a simple example of how to do this?

So my first lambda function has an output like:

```
return {"user_name" : user_name, "region" : region, "instance_id" : instance_id}
```

And my second lambda function tries to import with:

```
user_name = event["user_name"]
region = event["region"]
instance_id = event["instance_id"]
```

My stepfunction looks like:

```
{
         "StartAt": "CreateEC2Instance",
         "States": {
           "CreateEC2Instance": {
             "Type": "Task",
             "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
             "Parameters": {
               "FunctionName": "MY_ARN_1",
               "Payload": {
                  "region": "eu-central-1",
                  "user_name": "MY_USERNAME"
              }},
             "Next": "AttachEFStoEC2"
           },
            "AttachEFStoEC2": {
             "Type": "Task",
             "Resource":"MY_ARN_2",
             "End": true
         }
```

the error is:

```
{
  "error": "KeyError",
  "cause": {
    "errorMessage": "'user_name'",
    "errorType": "KeyError",
    "stackTrace": [
      "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    user_name = event[\"user_name\"]\n"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```json
{
         "StartAt": "CreateEC2Instance",
         "States": {
           "CreateEC2Instance": {
             "Type": "Task",
             "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
             "ResultPath": "$.randomstring",
             "Parameters": {
               "FunctionName": "MY_ARN_1",
               "Payload": {
                  "region": "eu-central-1",
                  "user_name": "MY_USERNAME"
              }},
             "Next": "AttachEFStoEC2"
           },
            "AttachEFStoEC2": {
             "Type": "Task",
             "Resource":"MY_ARN_2",
                   "Parameters": {
                       "outputfromearlierfunction.$": "$.randomstring.Payload"
                   },
             "End": true
         }
```

and then try to access within the function like

```
receivedinput = event.get('outputfromearlierfunction')
user_name = receivedinput["user_name"]
region = receivedinput["region"]
instance_id = receivedinput["instance_id"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation really helped me understand how parameters are stored :)